# raspberry pi easycap dc 60 capture problems

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mplayer

I am trying to capture video over EasyCap DC60 stk1160 (yellow cable) but on my raspbian 3.10.25 (raspberry pi) in mplayer video looks like this (green and messed video, artefacts): 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27YLQKNKZtw&feature=youtu.be

And after few seconds it ends with thi error: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cgQFc0i6vo&feature=youtu.be

I tried many settings (as well as vlc) but result is the same. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

wohooo, I found out it is problem with power. Raspberry pi is not strong enough to power usb easycap directly. When I use powered usb hub it works! :)